# POST Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou fazendo um CRM em codeigniter e estou com duvidas em uma seguinte situação, fiz um join entre minha tabela de clientes e chamados, todo cliente tem chamados
mas na hora de inserir, não to conseguindo.

```
function novoChamado($cliente_id){
  $data = array(
    'chamado_atividade'          => $this->input->post('chamado_atividade'),
    'chamado_duracao_minuto'     => $this->input->post('chamado_duracao_minuto'),
    'chamado_duracao_hora'       => $this->input->post('chamado_duracao_hora'),
    'chamado_assunto'            => $this->input->post('chamado_assunto'),
    'chamado_data'               => $this->input->post('chamado_data'),
    'chamado_hora'               => $this->input->post('chamado_hora'),
    'chamado_atendente_rf'       => $this->input->post('chamado_atendente_rf'),
    'chamado_atendente_cliente'  => $this->input->post('chamado_atendente_cliente'),
    'chamado_obs'                => $this->input->post('chamado_obs'),
    'chamado_telefone'           => $this->input->post('chamado_telefone'),
    'chamado_email'              => $this->input->post('chamado_email'),
    'chamado_id_cliente'         => $this->input->post($cliente_id),

  );
  $this->db->insert('chamado', $data);
}
```

nessa parte `chamado_id_cliente => $this->input->post($cliente_id)`
estou passando a variável de `id` do cliente para concluir o `Join`, mas ainda sim ele vai nulo para o banco.

Comment: apenas utilize $cliente_id

Comment: Veja que o teu input->post() vai pegar o que vem da tua view, por meio de um ajax ou formulario... e você está setando nele uma variavel.

Comment: Complica muito quando o autor da pergunta não interage com os que querem ajudar, aquele codigo não precisa ser feito já visto que `$this->input->post()` já retorna o `array` associativo que precisa se precisa criar mais algum item no array adicione uma linha somente com o `chamado_id_cliente`... até agora a sua pergunta não foi respondido por falta de informações.